# html - how to make 2 buttons on the same line in table

Tags: html

```
<table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <form method="post" action="update.php">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update"/>
      </form>

      <button>Delete</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to make the update button and delete button on the same line in table. 
However, from my above code, update button is at the top and delete button is at the bottom. 
How should I make them parallel on the table?

Comment: Tables should be reserved for tabular data. You shouldn't use table for layout. @pratikwebdev that solution would make a disparity in the number of columns in the table and might cause issues with table headers lining up properly, etc.

Comment: `<table>` tag is for information display. Use `<div>`s

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you want the button outside of the form? Anyway, just add `display: inline;` on the elements to bring them to the same line.

```html
<table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td>
<form method="post" action="update.php" style="display:inline">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update"/>
</form>
<button style="display:inline">Delete</button>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your 'delete button' is part of the form, let it inside of the form tags, like this:

```html
<table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <form method="post" action="update.php">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update"/>
        <input type="button" name="button" value="Delete"/>
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer using `display:inline` is perfectly valid. Another way to do it is using `float:left`

```html
<table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td>
<form method="post" action="update.php" >
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" style="float:left" />
</form>
<button style="margin-left:10px;" >Delete</button>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```